# angularjs custom directive value not posting to controller

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I'm new in angularjs,
I'm using custom directive which I have got here
[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dubilla/dj6mX/798/)
This directive not posting price value to controller after validating, I'm getting only name field value.

Here is my code:

```
<div class="form-group">
 <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Item Price</label>                  
 <div class="input-group">
 <span class="input-group-addon">$</span>
<input id="phone" class="form-control" ng-model="item.price" currency-input>
 </div>
</div>
```

Here is controller code:

```
angular.module('ngApp')
.controller('ItemCtrl',function($scope){

 $scope.item = {};

 $scope.addItem = function(){       
    console.log($scope.item);
 }
 })
.directive('currencyInput', function(){
return ......
};
```

});

Comment: try to narrow this down by using (and posting here) a minimal example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see that you're using `link` function to register your custom parser.

Note that this approach is more of a work-around for registering our custom `parsers` in to `NgModelController` as there's no direct API to do that from outside the directives.

I suggest the following changes to make it work.

1. `angular.module('minovateApp',[])` - You need to pass an empty Array indicating that there are no dependencies for this module.
2. The reason that you're not able to capture the value in model is because you're `not returning the parsed value` from your custom parser, So change your `link` function like below.

Inside your **currency-input** directive,

```
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {
       /* removed the return as it's not required */
        ctrl.$parsers.push(function(inputValue) {
           var inputVal = element.val();

           /* removing your logic for brevity */
           var res = intPart + decPart;

           if (res != inputValue) {
              ctrl.$setViewValue(res);
              ctrl.$commitViewValue();
              ctrl.$render();
           }

          /* return the final value once you're done parsing */
           return res;
    });
```

Here's a sample [Pen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zvwexK?editors=101) with the above mentioned changes. Hope this helps :)

Comment: perfect, it is working, I just put `return res:` 
Thank you @Arkantos